# ¿How can I compound where statements in a single query in Orator?

Tags: python, where-clause

I need to query a model for records between two dates, and I want to do it in a single query.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Orator docs](https://orator-orm.com/docs/0.9/query_builder.html#parameter-grouping), you can just chain statements when building your query

```
Event.where('date', '>', start_date).where('date', '<', finish_date)
```

or you can fall back to the advanced query scope and deal with the rows themselves and not use your models at all:

```
db.table('events').query().where('date', '>', start_date).where('date', '<', finish_date).get()
```

or you can use the already existing method `where between`

```
db.table('events').where_between('date', [start_date, finish_date]).get()
```

Additionally, there's the self explanatory `where_not_between` method. This last two methods are not available for the model, though.